# How to join several tables with sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I would like sort categories by number of visit

Categories have tasks, tasks have visits. I have four tables:

```
1)visits
     -id

2)category 
    -id

3)tasks
    -id
    -category_id

4)task_visit
   -task_id
   -visit_id
```

What I have at the moment:

-sort tasks by visits

```
SELECT count(task_id) as count, task_id
FROM task_visit
GROUP BY task_id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

-join categories with tasks

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
JOIN tasks
    ON categories.id = tasks.category_id
ORDER BY categories.id;
```

-try join categories with tasks and count visits(does't work) that in next sum it by category

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
JOIN tasks
    ON categories.id = tasks.category_id
ORDER BY categories.id
JOIN
(
    SELECT count(task_id) as count, task_id
    FROM task_visit
    GROUP BY task_id
    ORDER BY count
) ON tasks.id = task_visit.task_id;
```

So, how sort categories by number visit?

Comment: Can you add the tables like in the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understand)?

Comment: Give some sample data and what is is your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a join between the `category`, `tasks`, and `task_visit` tables, along with an aggregation by category:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    COUNT(tv.visit_id) AS cnt
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN tasks t
    ON c.id = t.category_id
LEFT JOIN task_visit tv
    ON tv.task_id = t.id
GROUP BY
    c.id
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```